# catch file.exists() SecurityException java

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to java and after some searching about catching the SecurityException for file.exists() I don't see people catching it so I'm unsure if I should catch the exception or not. Eclipse doesn't complain either way. This is a server expansion plugin and I wont have control when others run it.
Here's the code for the class:

```
public class ChatChannels {
    private JavaPlugin plugin;
    private HashSet<ChatChannel> chatChannels;
    private static ChatChannels instance;
    File configFile;
    FileConfiguration config;

    private ChatChannels(JavaPlugin plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
        configFile = new File(plugin.getDataFolder().getPath()
                .concat(File.separator).concat("Data"), "channels.yml");
        chatChannels = new HashSet<ChatChannel>();
        config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(configFile);

        if (!configFile.exists()) {
            return;
        }

        for (String channelName : config.getStringList("channels")) {
            chatChannels.add(new ChatChannel(channelName));
        }
    }

    public static ChatChannels getInstance(JavaPlugin plugin) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ChatChannels(plugin);
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

So, should I catch the exception or is it unnecessary?

```
try {
    if (!configFile.exists()) {
        return;
    }
} 
catch (SecurityException e) {
    plugin.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, configFile.getPath().concat(" read permission denied."), e);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule for catching all exceptions is "catch them at the level where you can take action." `SecurityException` is a `RuntimeException`, so you can choose to not catch it (and therefore have it propagate) without requiring your methods to explicitly throw `SecurityException`. So, what's your plan if you get one? Generally, the only thing you can do here is use a fallback path (because the one you were asking about is forbidden), or present an error to your user. Which choice you take, and at what level in the call stack you catch the exception, is up to you.

Comment: That clarifies it thanks! Because the path should always have read/write permission I'll disable the channels module and warn the user.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is if you should catch it and not how you do it (that's what you ask):

That entirely depends on your use case. If you want your application to react to said security exception being raised (like... trying again or informing the user) then you should catch it and react accordingly.

If you don't really care, you don't need to catch it.